# Test-path to local user profile folder path is returning true even after user profile is deleted. And there is no user folder present

Tags: windows, powershell, automation

Deleting User profile
    $UserFolderPath1 = "\$Server\C$\Users\$UserName"

```
Try {
         (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Server Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object {$_.LocalPath -eq "C:\Users\$UserName"}).Delete()
         Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "$UserName has been deleted from $Server"

       } Catch [System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException]{
         Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "ERROR: Profile is currently locked on $Server "

       } Catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException] {
         Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Blue "INFO: $UserName Profile does not exist on $host"

       } Catch {
         Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "ERROR: an unknown error occoured. The error response was $($error[0])"

       }
```

User folder is deleted but test-path c:\users\userprofilefolder is still showing as true

```
    if(test-path "$UserFolderPath1"){

       Write-host "user folder found"
       Get-ChildItem $UserFolderPath1 -Recurse | Remove-Item -recurse -Force  
       Remove-Item $UserFolderPath1 -Force   

    }
```

Comment: Well, to be technically accurate you are calling the .Delete method of a Win32_UserProfile WMI class. How certain are you that this method alsways completely deletes the folder?

Comment: I have manually logged into the server to find out if they are deleted. The problem I was facing test-path is returning true for non-existent folder. Someone pointed out if((test-path "$UserFolderPath1")) should work and it did but he/she had deleted the comment.

Comment: What is your code that creates `$UserFolderPath1`?

Comment: that is manual, there is no code for that. It's just a variable

Comment: Somewhere in your code that variable should be assigned a value. What is that code?

Comment: $UserFolderPath1 = "\$Server\C$\Users\$UserName" Is this what you are talking about?

Comment: Yes, that line would not produce a valid path. Is that literally the code that you are running?

Comment: To carry off of EBGreen, you should write-host `$UserFolderPath1` to see if the path is valid.

Comment: backslash got removed when pasting( not sure why) but my code has it and it runs perfectly $UserFolderPath1 = "\\$Server\C$\Users\$UserName"